# stick footer to bottom django template

Tags: python, css, django, templates

Good day, 
I am trying to stick footer to bottom django template layout, flex box and grid doesn`t help. May be in Django template another way?

Comment: Hello Dan, please provide code or project structure of your Django project so user can help you directly

Comment: nope, you can use css positioning for this. This tutorial can help you with it https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp#:~:text=position%3A%20sticky%3B&text=A%20sticky%20element%20toggles%20between,(like%20position%3Afixed).

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `position: fixed` in CSS

Comment: Or `position: sticky`:)

Comment: Thank you, i have already decided problem using "fixed"...)